# Why isn’t there a USB 3.1 Type B plug to 3.1 Type C receptacle

Tags: usb, hub, usb-c, cable, adapter

My desktop PC sits across the room from most of my appliances and I am emigrating all these devices off of wi-Fi/Bluetooth to good old fashion wired connections. (For reasons.) I’ve already run an Ethernet LAN cable across the room following the walls/doorframe and I’m happy with both how it looks and the added performance/security to my internet.

Because I want to future proof this set-up a bit(without breaking the bank) I need everything to be at least USB 3.0 or higher. (Btw, I also have a NAS server here that’s currently on an Ethernet hub that I’d like to run a usb cable to as a backup for whenever my internet settings change.)This seems to be the biggest stumbling block.

After educating myself on the craziness of all the different USB terms (and an earlier false start) I come to find out the hard way how unfriendly new generation USB tech is to long cables.

So here is where I boxed myself in. To solve this issue I went out and bought an expensive fiber optic USB 3.1 cable that has type-c connectors on both ends. [This very one from Amazon](https://a.co/d/7hRMmo9) (arrives soon).

So as I went shopping for a powered usb 3.0+ hub, all the ones I liked had Type-B receptacles… I ended up getting this guy as a backup [iDsonics](https://a.co/d/a8zbBSb) but I really hate the form factor. ( just for reference I like the old school boxy-type like here [sotMa 7 port hub](https://a.co/d/9mRkpem))

So I thought, okay this ought to be simple right? Just have find a 3.0+ type B plug (male) to USB 3.0+ Type C receptacle (female) adapter. Wow! A LOT harder than I though. I’ve officially given up and found a new appreciation for my backup hub. I can’t tell you the amount of times I almost pulled the trigger on a USB “3.0” type-c female to Type B male only to realize they left off the part where it only supports usb 2.0 speeds. [QianLink B to C(female)](https://a.co/d/bPLfXSD) So I would’ve dumped hundreds of dollars only to be bottle-knecked by a $7 part.

Really, I’m just whinning at this point, because I’ve decided to just stick with my “backup” hub; but in all honesty, I am curious why is this a nonexistent adapter? I downloaded the new USB Specifications to see if there was something forbidding it there but that stuff went over my head.

There are plenty of B-A adapters matching the specifications so why not B to C? If there isn’t some protocol restriction I think I’m going to try to make a custom-made adapter just out of spite lol.  I’d imagine my frustrations will become moot as the Type C plug gains more traction.

Answer (score 2):

C receptacle to legacy USB passive converters are explicitly forbidden by the specification.

However, Benson Leung have located some *active* ones, see his [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/m7rcu5/any_reliable_usbc_female_to_usba_male_adapters_yet/grducjr/) here. This: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074V4QBS4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074V4QBS4)

Once you have an A plug, USB 2.0 or 3.0 Type A Female to B Male are everywhere and cheap.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this [C to A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JHYKF3T) and then a regular [A to B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016YS8K4O). Both of these are USB 3 and you probably already have the second one.

Comment: Your right I do! I worry about the loss of performance but the adapters are cheap enough it doesn’t hurt to try! I’ll try it out and let you guys know if there’s any appreciable loss! Thanks!

Comment: C receptacle to legacy USB passive converters are explicitly forbidden by the specification.